# How to share HTML templates for many project

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, templates, partial-views

I have two SPA that use common code from the third application for serving assets.

These shared assets are CSS, JS, images and fonts so far and are served by rack server so I have an access locally and immediately when I change something in development, and also on production after I deploy this app.

What I'd like to have is also sharing html code, which is actually AngularJS partial templates. The only way I'm thinking about it is to somehow wrap these templates in JS code as HTML string and serve them as regular JS with stringified HTML.

Is there any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: putting these files on CDN wouldn't help you?

Comment: [angular-rails-templates](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates)

Comment: @MajoB, how can I fetch HTML files from CDN? How to use this locally?

Comment: @squixy you have to upload them manually